# The exponential of a matrix

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

I have an exponential that is raised to the power of a 2x1 matrix and I am wondering what to do with it.

[The exact reference I have](http://snap.stanford.edu/nipsgraphs2009/papers/xiang-paper.pdf) refers to $e^{\theta u}$ where $u = {\begin{bmatrix}a\\z\end{bmatrix}}$

Any ideas?

Comment: The exponential of a matrix is usually defined for square matrices. Could you write down a bit more and explain what the framework is?

Comment: Do you have sg like this $2^{\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}}$?

Comment: All references I can find also relate to square matrices. In the paper I am reading it refers to $e^{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}}$?

Comment: Its a paper called 'Modeling Relationship Strength in
Online Social Networks'. Is that enough to be able to find it @Wouter?

Comment: So I think the fact you were silent about was that $\theta$ is a vector too. What I can see in the paper is $$\exp(\theta^\top u),$$ which is a usual scalar exponential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If [this](http://snap.stanford.edu/nipsgraphs2009/papers/xiang-paper.pdf) is the paper you are talking about, then the matrix exponentials in that paper (like in eq. (3)) are actually scalar exponentials. The column matrix $u_t$ is left-multiplied by a row matrix $\theta_t^T$, and the result $\theta_t^T u_t$ is a number, not a matrix.

Comment: That is the paper @Wouter. Thanks! So am I right in thinking that for each $u_t$ there is a corresponding 1x2 matrix? I really would love to be able to discuss this paper with someone :-(

Comment: It looks like the authors adopted the convention of using bold font $\mathbf{u}$ for vectorial quantities and normal font $b$ for scalar quantities. The $\mathbf{u}$ are defined underneath (3), but since $\mathbf{a}$ is vectorial they are not $2\times 1$, they are $(\text{dimensionality of }\mathbf{a}+1)\times 1$. And indeed, for every one of these $\mathbf{u}_t$ there appears to be a $\mathbf{\theta}_t$.